# Setting screen resolution for Xvfb in AIX machine

Tags: aix, dpi, xvfb

How do you set the screen resolution for the Xvfb server?screen resolution for the Xvfb server is 100X100.I would like to change screen resolution for the Xvfb server as 90x90 . Please tell me how to change screen resolution for the Xvfb server in AIX machine

Comment: I don't have an A IX machine to test, but on Ubuntu with xvfb version 1.15.1, you can use `-dpi 90` to set the dots-per-inch (from original title of question). For the current title, `-screen 0 90x90x24` (replace 24 with 8 or 16 for less colorspace) will set a 90 pixel by 90 pixel display. Combining both gives a virtual display that is 1 inch by 1 inch in "physical" size. These options might work on the AIX version you have.